# After installing Linux Mint, only a terminal is showen when I boot into it

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dual-boot

I have been using windows for as far back as I could remember and developing in virtual boxes but I have decided to install Linux Mint onto a second hard drive on my main computer. Sadly, when I boot into the partition which holds Linux Mint, it only displays a terminal where I can only perform basic commands. I'd like to have a GUI rather than a terminal, but I do not know what do do even after googling the topic. Please help!
-BK

Comment: What's the output of your Xorg.0.log?. Run `tail -n 20 /var/log/Xorg.0.log/Xorg.0.log` Does the output show the words `BusyBox` or `initramfs`?.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you've done, how you installed Mint (was it GUI based during the installation?). Are there any error messages? What is the output of `sudo service mdm status`?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with new installations when there were driver configuration problems.  First check your xorg log file to see what if anything happened: less /var/log/Xorg.0.log should tell you what failed.  Easiest solution probably to reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that there was an error setting up the OS (especially if you did not use an ISO file provided by the official Linux Mint website). 
You could try using the `startx` command if you installed a minimalistic version of the Linux Mint kernel environment. 
Your best bet is to run `which startx` to see if there is a `startx` command, and if there is, then use it. 
If there is *no* `startx` command, then try reinstalling Linux Mint from the ground up again. 
If that still is a problem go to `/boot` and see if there is a broken file there. I'm afraid that if that doesn't work you might want to use your first drive for Linux Mint and get rid or move Windows.